# How can I use Javascript with PayPal Java Code?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I've got a unique situation. I'm trying to implement PayPal as a payment gateway, but I need to be able to adjust the shipping costs. I can do so for credit cards using javascript, with this code

```
         let cart_total = {{ $cartTotal }};
    
       //let starting_rate = parseFloat({{ $selected_rate['amount'] }});
    
       let starting_rate = parseFloat({{ $new_rate }});

   console.log(starting_rate);

   $(".rate-value").click(function(){
    let new_rate =   $("input[name='rate']:checked").data('amount');
    let final_rate = new_rate;

    document.getElementById("new_rate").innerHTML = final_rate;
    document.getElementById("charge_rate").innerHTML = parseFloat(final_rate) + parseFloat(cart_total);
    document.getElementById("send_rate").innerHTML = parseFloat(final_rate) + parseFloat(cart_total);
      // alert(new_rate);
       console.log(final_rate);


   });
```

But this code won't work with the PayPal Java Code

```
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: {{ $cartTotal + $new_rate }}
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
//This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Paypal appears to have its own JavaScript API and Java does not appear to be needed. You don't appear to be showing any Java-specific code in your question, and so I'm not sure where Java plays into your question, your code, or your problem. Can you please clarify your question if possible?

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

("Java" is a separate language, this question is strictly about "JavaScript")

The solution is to do all calculations inside/from:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
```

You can call other functions or reference any variables that are defined at that scope. So if you need to calculate a "final_rate", write a function that does this and call it from all the places in your code that need to make use of it (one for each payment method such as PayPal and credit cards, it would seem)

Comment: Thank you. I know that Java is its own programming language. Thanks, I'll research how to do this.